# How many combinations of divisors of N sum up to N?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

For a given integer $N$, how many different combinations of divisors are there such that their sum equals $N$?

For example, with $N = 6$, I count 7 different sums:

```
6 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
  = 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
  = 2 + 2 + 1 + 1
  = 2 + 2 + 2
  = 3 + 1 + 1 + 1
  = 3 + 2 + 1
  = 3 + 3
```

but I have no idea how to know how many of them are there without writing them down.

**PS:** I would also like to know how many sums are there if each divisor appears only once (would be $1$ for $N=6$) and if there are more numbers that equal the sum of their divisors (like $6=3+2+1$). I guess that is too much for a single question, but pointing me in the right direction would already help a lot, as atm I have even no idea what terms to search for.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a nice closed form solution. We can rephrase this problem as finding the number of solutions to the Frobenius equation

$$k_1x_1 + k_2x_2 + \dots + k_nx_n = M,\text{ }k_i \in \mathbb{N}$$

where $M$ is the integer in question, $x_i$ are its positive divisors, and $\mathbb{N}$ contains $0$. This is not easy; see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67163/number-of-solutions-of-frobenius-equation) about finding the number of solutions.

There may be a more clever number theoretic approach that works; for example, some initial observation shows that primes will always have one way that works (consisting only of ones); the least bound for any composite integer is the sum of the proper divisors, and that the only composite integers with this least value are the squares of primes. Hopefully someone with a better understanding of number theory can more fully elaborate on this.